# Overlaying colors on times series plot based upon categorical variables?

Tags: r, graphics, plot

I have a time series plot of two variables (tidal elevation and data logger temperature) and have been looking at how they interact in the hopes of factoring out (in a exploratory/qualitative way) the influence of first upon the second. However, in some cases the influence has been the opposite of what I expected and I'm thinking that a third variable (weather) is probably having an influence and I'd like to check it out.

It would be really helpful to just overlay some colors or grayscale over the plot that corresponds to different levels of the weather variable. For instance, clear days could be light blue, overcast days could be dark blue, etc. Does anyone have an idea of how to do this? I have included a bit of my data as well as a graph. (For graph: blue line is tide, red line is temp, black line at tide=0 is when the logger is exposed).

```
head(Tide.Temp, 4)
         Date.Dab      Temp.Dab  Tide.Dab  Weath.Dab
1 2013-07-28 21:30:00       68.9      9.4      Clear
2 2013-07-28 22:00:00       68.9      9.5      Clear
3 2013-07-28 22:30:00       68.9      9.5      Clear
4 2013-07-28 23:00:00       68.9      9.2      Clear
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please edit your question to contain the output of `dput(head(Tide.Temp,10))`?

Comment: See `?xblocks` in the zoo package. Follow the first example on that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend plotting a horizontal line somewhere where it does not obscure your time series (e.g., at the overall minimum *y* value), color-coded for weather.

In the code below, I code weather as a `factor` and use the fact that R stores `factor`s internally as integers, so we can simply say `col=weather`, and the `factor` will be silently converted to integers, and then the i-th color from the `palette()` will be used.

```
library(zoo)
set.seed(1)
temp <- cumsum(rnorm(1000))
timestamps <- as.POSIXct("2014-01-01 00:00")+seq_along(temp)*30*60
weather <- as.factor(rep(sample(c("Clear","Cloudy","Rainy"),200,replace=TRUE),
  times=rpois(200,10))[seq_along(temp)])

temp.zoo <- zoo(x=temp,order.by=timestamps)
zero.zoo <- zoo(x=min(temp),order.by=timestamps)

plot(temp.zoo,xlab="",ylab="")
points(zero.zoo,col=weather,pch=22)
legend(x="topright",pch=22,
  col=seq_along(levels(weather)),pt.bg=seq_along(levels(weather)),
  legend=levels(weather))
```

[image: weather time series]

Comment: Upvoted and accepted because this is a really good alternative, thanks.